# WPF: Animated Line slows down UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm drawing a line in my UI that needs to be updated everytime the graphics are redrawn. Since I'd like my UI still to be responsive (which is it not, at the moment), I'm using a backgroundworker that gets called everytime the UI is rendered. As mentioned, at the moment the UI becomes unresponsive and slow when the line is drawn. Is there anything I could change to improve my software?

This is the code I'm using (at least the parts that are relevant).

```
BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
_worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Worker_DoWork);
CompositionTarget.Rendering += new EventHandler(CompositionTarget_Rendering);

void CompositionTarget_Rendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_worker.IsBusy) { _worker.RunWorkerAsync(); }
}
```

The Line I'm using is generated out of an array of Point[]. To make sure nothing else is slowing the software down, I stripped the line generation down to just using dummy-values:

```
void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
    {
        Point[] line = new Point[480];

        MySegment1.Points.Clear();
        bool isStart = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            line[i] = new Point(0, 0);
            if (isStart)
            {
                MyFigure1.StartPoint = line[i];
                isStart = false;
            }
            else
                MySegment1.Points.Add(new Point(i, line[i].Y + 10));
        }
    });
}
```

The XAML for the line looks like this:

```
<Path Stroke="GreenYellow" StrokeThickness="2" Name="MyPath1"  Grid.Column="1">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigureCollection>
                    <PathFigure x:Name="MyFigure1" StartPoint="0,0">
                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                            <PathSegmentCollection>
                                <PolyBezierSegment x:Name="MySegment1"/>
                            </PathSegmentCollection>
                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathFigureCollection>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Thanks a lot for any recommandations!

**EDIT:** In addition to Clemens answer I also changed the `DispatcherPriority` to `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle`, which also increased the responsibility of the UI a lot. I think this is a state I can live with at the moment... :)

Comment: Your background worker is running Worker_DoWork on a background thread?  Yes?  Well, no.  You're using the dispatcher to run your entire update algo on the UI thread.  Your background worker doesn't do jack squat except enqueue the method on the dispatcher.  Honestly, the level of skill required to do what you want to do is pretty high; I'd suggest dumping animation, or just buy a control that can do what you need the way you need to do it.

Comment: Thank you for that honest opinion - what skillset would be required to get into that? I'm really interested in learning how to achieve this by myself rather than buying anything...

Comment: Firstly, a good understanding of how multithreaded application programming is done.  Secondly, a deep knowledge of how UI is rendered in WPF.  Third, most necessary for animated complex graphs, how to program accelerated 2d and 3d graphics in WPF via DX.  The level of complexity of these three starts very high, and rises exponentially.  That's why it's always better to buy than to write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There would be no need for all this BackgroundWorker "optimization" if you did not update the PolyBezierSegment point by point, but instead create a new `PointCollection` and assign it to the `Points` property of the PolyBezierSegment:

```
private Random random = new Random(); // creates some sample data

private void CompositionTarget_Rendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var line = new Point[480];

    for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++ )
    {
        line[i] = new Point(i, random.Next(0, 100));
    }

    MyFigure1.StartPoint = line[0];
    MySegment1.Points = new PointCollection(line); // here
}
```

Please note also that WPF provides more efficient ways of rendering graphics than a PathGeometry in a Path control. You may start reading the [Graphics and Multimedia](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742562.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: Wow, thank you. That's a huge boost. And thanks for the recommended article!